# How can I merge two data sets with ID variation in stata

Tags: merge, panel, stata

I have following two data sets.

The first one from children looks like this.

ID  year Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 ....

101 2014 1 2 2 2

101 2016 1 2 2 2

101 2017 1 2 2 2

101 2018 1 2 2 2

401 2014 1 2 2 2

401 2015 1 2 3 3

401 2016 1 2 2 2

401 2017 1 2 1 1

401 2018 1 2 2 2

402 2014 1 1 0 3

402 2015 1 1 2 2

402 2016 1 1 2 2

402 2017 1 1 3 3

402 2018 1 1 2 3

Here's the second one from their parents.

ID year Q101 Q102

1 2014 1 3

1 2015 1 3

1 2016 1 3

1 2017 1 2

1 2018 1 2

2 2014 2 .

2 2015 1 2

2 2016 . .

2 2017 1 3

2 2018 2 .

4 2014 1 3

4 2015 1 3

4 2016 1 3

4 2017 1 3

4 2018 1 3

So the parent data ID can be matched to the children data ID deleted last two digits. It seems that parent ID 4 has two children.

I tried
merge 1:m ID using kids data as the master data set.
but it didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: So, on this information the parent identifier is `floor(ID/100)` in the children dataset.  You need to `merge 1:m` or `merge m:1` -- depending on which you way you do it -- on the parent identifier, which must have the same name in both datasets.

Comment: See the Stata tag wiki or https://www.statalist.org/forums/help#stata on how to present a real or realistic data example using code. That would help you get good answers faster.

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks for the information

Comment: I run this. `save kids,replace`, `use kids`, `merge m:1 floor(ID/100) parents` and the error shows up saying "factor variables and time-series operators not allowed."

Comment: Sorry, not what I was hinting at. You do need to use that recipe to `generate` a new variable and in any case `merge` requires one or more variable names on which to merge (not expressions). As I said, the identifiers must have the same name in both datasets.

Comment: And you need to `merge` on `year` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting good answers is made more likely by (a) attempting code and showing what you tried and (b) giving data in the form of code anybody using Stata can run. The code here follows from editing your post and is close to what you could get directly by using `dataex` as explained in the Stata tag wiki or indeed at `help dataex` in an up-to-date Stata or one in which you installed `dataex` from SSC.

```
clear 
input ID year Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 
101 2014 1 2 2 2
101 2016 1 2 2 2
101 2017 1 2 2 2
101 2018 1 2 2 2
401 2014 1 2 2 2
401 2015 1 2 3 3
401 2016 1 2 2 2
401 2017 1 2 1 1
401 2018 1 2 2 2
402 2014 1 1 0 3
402 2015 1 1 2 2
402 2016 1 1 2 2
402 2017 1 1 3 3
402 2018 1 1 2 3
end 

gen IDP = floor(ID/100)
save children 

clear 
input ID year Q101 Q102
1 2014 1 3
1 2015 1 3
1 2016 1 3
1 2017 1 2
1 2018 1 2
2 2014 2 .
2 2015 1 2
2 2016 . .
2 2017 1 3
2 2018 2 .
4 2014 1 3
4 2015 1 3
4 2016 1 3
4 2017 1 3
4 2018 1 3
end 

rename ID IDP 

merge 1:m IDP year using children 

list 

     +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | IDP   year   Q101   Q102    ID   Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4            _merge |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |   1   2014      1      3   101    1    2    2    2       matched (3) |
  2. |   1   2015      1      3     .    .    .    .    .   master only (1) |
  3. |   1   2016      1      3   101    1    2    2    2       matched (3) |
  4. |   1   2017      1      2   101    1    2    2    2       matched (3) |
  5. |   1   2018      1      2   101    1    2    2    2       matched (3) |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |   2   2014      2      .     .    .    .    .    .   master only (1) |
  7. |   2   2015      1      2     .    .    .    .    .   master only (1) |
  8. |   2   2016      .      .     .    .    .    .    .   master only (1) |
  9. |   2   2017      1      3     .    .    .    .    .   master only (1) |
 10. |   2   2018      2      .     .    .    .    .    .   master only (1) |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------|
 11. |   4   2014      1      3   401    1    2    2    2       matched (3) |
 12. |   4   2015      1      3   401    1    2    3    3       matched (3) |
 13. |   4   2016      1      3   402    1    1    2    2       matched (3) |
 14. |   4   2017      1      3   401    1    2    1    1       matched (3) |
 15. |   4   2018      1      3   402    1    1    2    3       matched (3) |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------|
 16. |   4   2014      1      3   402    1    1    0    3       matched (3) |
 17. |   4   2015      1      3   402    1    1    2    2       matched (3) |
 18. |   4   2016      1      3   401    1    2    2    2       matched (3) |
 19. |   4   2017      1      3   402    1    1    3    3       matched (3) |
 20. |   4   2018      1      3   401    1    2    2    2       matched (3) |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As far as the `merge` is concerned the essentials are identifiers with the same name(s) in both datasets and the correct pattern for merging. The parent identifier is only implied by the children dataset.